# Golang, add item and return new struct with random string

Tags: go

I am trying to figure out how to set up a basic endpoint in golang. I have a call that takes a payload and adds it to a list (in memory right now). Previously it was just returning the exact payload it was getting. I would like it to return a new json object with a randomly generated string. Here it what it looked like initially :

in my repo.go

```
func RepoCreateActivity(t Activity) Activity {
    activities = append(activities, t)
    return t
}
```

and this works fine. However I would like to return a different object with randomly generated string, here is what I have tried

in my repo.go (the randomstring function is from a bit of googling - https://siongui.github.io/2015/04/13/go-generate-random-string/ )

```
 func RandomString(strlen int) string {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UTC().UnixNano())
    const chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"
    result := make([]byte, strlen)
    for i := 0; i < strlen; i++ {
        result[i] = chars[rand.Intn(len(chars))]
    }
    return string(result)
}

func RepoCreateActivity(t Activity) ActivityReturn {
    activities = append(activities, t)
    b := ActivityReturn({Cgid: RandomString(10)})
    return b
}
```

The actvitityReturn.go looks like :

```
package main

type ActivityReturn struct {
    Cgid   string   `json:"cgid"`
}
```

I cannot seem to get this right. I just want the call to return a 
`{ cgid : "random string here" }`. I am still working through learning golang and any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What behavior are you experiencing that doesn't seem right?  Errors?  Unintended behavior?  On the surface, I don't see anything wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be creating your struct incorrectly. Could you perhaps give this a try?

```
func RepoCreateActivity(t Activity) ActivityReturn {
    activities = append(activities, t)
    b := ActivityReturn{Cgid: RandomString(10)} // remove parens
    return b
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are only worried about the output in that manner, then following will work:

```
func RepoCreateActivity(t Activity) string {
activities = append(activities, t)
b := ActivityReturn{Cgid: RandomString(10)}
temp,_:=json.Marshal(b)
return string(temp)
}
```

Note that output in this case is string.